# How will my .Net app acquire the necessary tokens from a user who will subscribe to my app?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am making a .NET application that will allow potential users to upload invoices they make on my app to their quickbooks account that they have set up and synchronized  with their QBD version.

what steps will they/I need to take so that when they use my app, it will upload invoices to their account?  Is it:

a) when they set up their account with the Intuit AppCenter, they will pick my app from the app center services (in doing so, it will generate a set of oAuth connection parameters for me to put into my app to push invoices to their account, if so how will I get these)?

b) Will I set up an account via the Intuit Platform Partners, and ask the user to use my account ID and Password by which they will "create new app" under my account for the purposes of generating oAuth connection information for my app to use?

c) Something different from the a) and b)?

Thanks!

Comment: If you post what language you're using, someone can provide sample code too.

Comment: My app is an ASP.NET app with code-behinds in C#.  I get how to make my app get the oAuth Tokens, at least technically (the QuickBooksApiDotNetWebFormsSampleApp project is a great example to learn from).

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth stuff is specifically designed to allow end-users to push a set of OAuth tokens/credentials from QuickBooks to your app. You then store the OAuth tokens, and use those to communicate with QuickBooks.

This *is* an accurate description of what happens, yes:

> a) when they set up their account with the Intuit AppCenter, they will
>   pick my app from the app center services (in doing so, it will
>   generate a set of oAuth connection parameters for me to put into my
>   app to push invoices to their account, ...

You can read more about that process in the docs:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0020_connect/0011_from_the_intuit_app_center

The other scenario is that, if you allow it, the user may choose to connect to QuickBooks from within your app. In this case, they'll click the "Connect to QuickBooks" button (see the docs here: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0020_connect/0010_from_within_your_app) which forwards them to Intuit's site, generates the OAuth tokens, and then sends them back to your site with the OAuth tokens.

In either case, the OAuth tokens will be *sent to you* so that you can store them and use them to communicate with the QuickBooks APIs.

This:

> ... and ask
>   the user to use my account ID and Password by which they will "create
>   new app" under my account for the purposes of generating oAuth
>   connection information for my app to use?

Is absolutely *not* what you want them to do. The whole point of OAuth is that you *don't* need to share any usernames/passwords of any time with any one.

**Here are some additional answers to your other comments:**

> The part I am trying to figure out is what my customers will need to
>   do to be able to benefit from my app and its QuickBooks Integration
>   functionality.

They will need to log in to their Intuit.com account, and follow the prompts to connect their QuickBooks company to your app (i.e. follow the prompts to forward the OAuth credentials to your app).

> Sounds like he/she will need to set up some account with ID and
>   password.

If they don't already have an Intuit.com account, they will be prompted to create one during the OAuth process. In the case of QuickBooks Online, they will ALWAYS already have an Intuit.com account (it's the same thing they use to log in to QuickBooks Online).

> Now it seems to me that there are two ways that the customer can set
>   up accounts with Intuit.

They can set up an account through AppCenter, or within QuickBooks desktop directly (when you install the software, it prompts you) or if you're using any Intuit service already (e.g. QuickBooks Online) then you use your existing QuickBooks Online account.

Developer.Intuit.com accounts are *only for developers* (e.g. for YOU). Your end-users *will not have a developer.intuit.com account*. Nor do they need one.

> a) what are the differences between the two?

Developer.Intuit.com accounts are only for developers. Your end-user *will never see the developer.intuit.com website, nor will they see the option to "Create an App".*

> b) which should be used if the customer wants to set up syncing their
>   QBD? c)Which should be used if the customer wants to use my .net App.
>   d)Which should the customer use if they want both (b) and (c)? e) If
>   the customer creates an account the 2nd way, won't they get confused
>   by all the "developer" lingo?

None of those questions are applicable - end-users *will never see or be prompted about any of the developer stuff*. The only reason you see that is because you're registered as a developer. Normal end-users *will not be*, and thus won't have any of these options.

> f)What if the customer has already synced their QBD with intuit?

Then they can just log in to their existing account to get connected (i.e. to send the OAuth credentials over to your app).

Comment: Dear Consolibyte,  Thank you SO MUCH for the quick turn-around you and Manas give these [Intuit-Partner-Platform] questions.  I am finding it very difficult to get answers from the Intuit support center itself.  That being said, I would really like to have a conversation with someone from intuit by phone or chat because my questions are with regard to the business model being proposed by Intuit.  However, if that is not possible, then I'll make the most of this venue.  Thanks again.

Comment: I don't work for Intuit, so I can't help you there - we just happen to do a lot of QuickBooks consulting. But, if you submit a support ticket to them they should get back to you: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/9_other_resources/0030_support/developer_support

Comment: The part I am trying to figure out is what my customers will need to do to be able to benefit from my app and its QuickBooks Integration functionality.  Sounds like he/she will need to set up some account with ID and password.  I assume this will be used when they are in my app and want it to connect to their QuickBooks data (online OR desktop).  Now it seems to me that there are two ways that the customer can set up accounts with Intuit.  One is to go through the Intuit App Center. The other is to go through "Developer.intuit.com"  Next Comment will hold my questions.  Thx.

Comment: Herein are my questions:  a) what are the differences between the two?  b) which should be used if the customer wants to set up syncing their QBD?  c)Which should be used if the customer wants to use my .net App.  d)Which should the customer use if they want both (b) and (c)?  e) If the customer creates an account the 2nd way, won't they get confused by all the "developer" lingo? f)What if the customer has already synced their QBD with intuit?

Comment: With regard to Intuit's support tickets.  I had received responses to the first two or three tickets.  After that, I got no response and found that they began marking them as closed even though I had no communication from them.

Comment: Intuit support tickets are never closed unless the response is sent and the developer is satisfied or has not responded to their questions within some time. Can you check the spam folders or verify the email address you use?

Comment: I see, that your queries were answered in those tickets. If you still need more information, you can always reply back on that ticket and it will reopen. We do not have a hard close on the tickets. I apologize if you are still facing issues.

Comment: Nimisha - thank you.  Spam folder was full responses from Intuit Support.  Cannot speak on behalf of Consolibyte, but in my case, I was wrong and apologize to Intuit Support for any remarks to the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your questions:
A developer can choose to get his app listed on the appcenter or not depending on mkting requirements.
To understand the difference in the process-  you can create a sample and then on developer.intuit.com, go to My Apps-> manage my app-> select your app. Then test connections.
You can use any of the above to use QBD data. Please see the additional info too that I have provided.

Also go through the link which consolibyte has mentioned.
If you are logging in from appcenter app, then since you are already logged in, then only OAUTH will be required.
In logging from within your app, you do not need to provide your user Id and password. The user needs to register for the first time  with Intuit.com and then OAUTH process follows for him. These open id/email details can be saved in your db so that user need to enter them a next time.

The customer is never about the details of the developer except for the app which will access their company data.

The sync manager for QBD 
OAUTH authorizes your app to connect to their company files.

Any of the above can be used to access QBD data.

The sync manager runs manually or automatically. So, customer can choose to sync/not sync his data.
---------------Addtional info----------

There are two ways to integrate with QuickBooks, the first is with REST APIs and the second is with the downloadable QBXML SDK v12. The REST APIs and that integration model is for applications that are to be sold to customers via our Appcenter. They are generally Saas applications.

The second model is the QBXML sdk which is available for anyone to use, especially for custom integrations.

The reference for the QBXML SDK is here
http://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

Please go through:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits  ->QBXML SDK

Lastly through the QBXML SDK you can add a custom field to any entity you want. See the reference above and take a look at DataExt Add Request. and once added Query Request. I believe this will give you what you are looking for.

### Keep in mind this is for QuickBooks for Windows not QuickBooks Online.

You can go through FAQ page too-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq

Answer (score 0):

I am settled at this point from what Consolibyte has shared and what I have learned also.  The whole picture (for me at least) is that both the Developer Account AND the App Center Account is needed. The Developer account provides the consumer key, consumer secret and application token that the .Net app will use to authenticate with Intuit.  The App Center Account is needed to allow the user to sync their QuickBooks Desktop data to a location where the app center (and other 3rd party apps) can have access to it (after user authorizes of course), and to give it's user an ID and Password needed to authorize the .net app ( or any app for that matter) to access his/her Intuit data.  It is the combination of the Developer Account's tokens and the App center Account's ID and password that allow the generation of an authentication/access token by which the .Net app can instantiate a Dataservices object so it can read/write to the user's instance of QB data in the App Center.  Apart from the user creating an account in the App Center and synching their QB Desktop data with it, There should be little or nothing else to do except provide the ID and password, providing the .Net app is coded right. I am not talking about OpenID in this case, but do know that it uses the same ID and password.

...so I'm good.  Thx.